# How to forbid git commit if there are untracked files?

Tags: git, commit, gitignore, git-commit

Sometimes, it makes sense to forbid git commit when there are untracked files, because you should add them either to files to commit or gitignore. And an option like -f to force this commit is also necessary. So is there any option/plugin/etc to do that? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a [pre-commit](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) hook that exits with a non-zero value if you find untracked files (you could examine the output of [`git status --porcelain -u`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-status.html) to determine their presence--look for lines beginning with "?").  Then you can override the commit verification with `git commit --no-verify` if you don't care about the untracked files.

*Edit:* Thanks to @Jefromi; I don't have my git environment at hand to test.  He also notes that this command should identify the presence of untraced files: `git status -u | grep '^# Untracked files:$'`.

Comment: I think you want to examine the output of `git status --porcelain -u`, not `git status -u`. All the `-u` does is make sure that untracked files will be listed, which they will be anyway unless it's turned off in the config. The `--porcelain` is what makes it easy to parse with a script, with the `??` at the beginning of the line, instead of you having to read and find the "Untracked files" section. That option was added in v1.6.4.

Comment: Of course, if all you need to know is if there are untracked files, just do `git status -u | grep '^# Untracked files:$'`