# Pycharm, django south migration files and git integration

Tags: python, git, pycharm, django-south

As you know, django south migration files are generated by command below;

`# python manage.py schemamigration model_name --auto`

Sometimes, I forget to add the migration files to project repository.

Is there a way to display reminder of the manually generated migration files in pycharm to add git repo before committing other project files to the repository?

Comment: I think there isn't. PyCharm displays new files using red color in "Project files" list.

Comment: I know it can show new files in red, but migration files are laying under sub folders. And I forget them, because I don't see them If sub folders are not expanded.

Comment: You could write pre-commit hook which check if there are some untracked files, if yes - abort committing. [How to forbid git commit if there are untracked files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533470/how-to-forbid-git-commit-if-there-are-untracked-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to pancakes's comment, I enabled pre-commit hook and append lines below:

```
ud=`git status -u | grep '^Untracked files:$'`

if [ -n "$ud" ];
then 
        cat <<\EOF 
Warning: There are new files exists and not added to project repo.
EOF
        exit 1
fi
```

Now, git gives warning while new files available and breaks process before commit. This also working on PyCharm with error popup.